# Is there a way to use Regex to split I[1,2]?

Tags: c#, regex

I am extracting a string from an XML file in C# and need the second number in `"I[1,2]"` which would be `2`.

```
  Regex regex = new Regex(@"\[.*?\]");
  MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(inputChannel.Value);

  var result = matches[0].Value.Split().Where(x => x.StartsWith("[") && x.EndsWith("]"))
                 .Select(x => x.Replace("[", string.Empty).Replace("]", string.Empty))
                 .ToList();
```

where `inputChannel.value = "I[1;2]"`

This code gets the two numbers and sticks them into a list but is there a way to split the two numbers and put them into a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using split, you can use a capture group to get the second number.

```
I\[[0-9]+;([0-9]+)]
```

- `I\[` Match `I[`
- `[0-9]+;` Match 1+ digits 0-9 and `;`
- `([0-9]+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ digits 0-9
- `]` Match a `]` char

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jh95vS/1).

```
string pattern = @"I\[[0-9]+;([0-9]+)]";
string input = @"I[1;2]";        
Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern); 
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value); // 2
```

Or using lookarounds:

```
(?<=I\[[0-9]+;)[0-9]+(?=])
```

- `(?<=I\[[0-9]+;)` Positive lookbehind, assert `I[`, 1+ digits followed by `;` to the left
- `[0-9]+` Match 1+ digits 0-9
- `(?=])` Positive lookahead, assert `]` to the right

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Hn8kMv/1).

```
string pattern = @"(?<=I\[[0-9]+;)[0-9]+(?=])";
string input = @"I[1;2]";        
Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern); 
Console.WriteLine(m.Value); // 2
```